# Insert query with variables

Tags: php, insert, user-profile

I have the following query

```
function Add_Oddjob ($Add_Oddjob){
            //global $MemberID;
            //$update = array();
            array_walk($Add_Oddjob, 'array_sanitize');

            //foreach($Add_Oddjob as $field=>$data){ //loop through update data in Add_Oddjob.php
                //$update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\''; 
            }
            //mysql_query("INSERT INTO `oddjob`($field) VALUES ($data)") or die (mysql_error());
            echo "INSERT INTO `oddjob`(`MemberID`, `OddJobName`, `Description`,`DaysAvailable`) VALUES ('$MemberID','".$_POST['OddJobName']."', '".$_POST['Description']."','$daysavailable')";
            die ();
```

The echo outputs the following:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: MemberID in \oddjobexchange\core\functions\user.php on line 69

Notice: Undefined variable: daysavailable in \oddjobexchange\core\functions\user.php on line 69
INSERT INTO `oddjob`(`MemberID`, `OddJobName`, `Description`,`DaysAvailable`) VALUES ('','Painting', 'Test ','')
```

This is the array im using in an other page:

```
        if (isset($_POST['OddJobName']) && isset($_POST['Description']) && isset($_POST['DaysAvailable']) && empty($errors) === true){//if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) { //if (isset(empty($_POST['OddJobName'])) && isset(empty($_POST['Description'])) && isset(empty($_POST['DaysAvailable'])) === false && empty($errors) === true)
        $daysavailable='';
        foreach ($_POST['DaysAvailable'] as $value)
        {

        $daysavailable .=$value." ";
        }

        $Add_Oddjob = array (
            'MemberID'      => $MemberID,
            'OddJobName'    => $_POST['OddJobName'],
            'Description'   => $_POST['Description'],
            'DaysAvailable' => $daysavailable, 

            );

            Add_Oddjob ($Add_Oddjob);

            if(success){
             header('Location: member.php?username='.$username);
             exit ();
            }
        } else if (empty($errors) === false){
            //otherwise output errors
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }
```

What can I do to make the `$MemberID` and `$daysavailable` work within the query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use **array variables** like this. Use like,

```
$Add_Oddjob['MemberID']
```

Also, it is not `$daysavailable`. It should be `$Add_Oddjob['DaysAvailable']`

Comment: Originally thats what I tried but I get: Notice: Undefined variable: Add_Oddjob. Not sure what im doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lairds No. This should work.. Check your array_walk output. If the structure is correct, you can access like this